# Cannot find module 'prettier'

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint, package.json, prettier

I updated all packages but still getting this error after running **npm run serve**:

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
>   Error: Cannot find module 'prettier' Occurred while linting /home

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.2.1",
    "firebase": "^7.0.0",
    "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-flickity": "^1.2.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.0.19",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^4.4.95",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.3",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.7",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.6.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-console": "off"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}

**"@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",** is listed in the dependencies. How to fix this issue? (I'm using VSCODE on Ubuntu)
```

I tried multiple times deleting **package-lock.json** and **node_modules** and  running npm install afterwards. Nothing fixes it - even updating all packages globally.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

**Prettier** is a peer dependency of 
**@vue/eslint-config-prettier** so you need to add it to your own dependencies:

```
npm install --save-dev prettier
```

Answer (score 14):

if you're using yarn 3, and `yarn add --dev prettier` doesn't solve your problem, try this:

1. `cmd` + `shift` + `p`
2. in the dropdown, search for `preferences: open user settings (json)`
3. add `"prettier.prettierPath": ".yarn/sdks/prettier/index.js"` to your json file.

This tells your editor to find the module in the path you added.

**NOTE**: If there is not `sdks` directory in `.yarn` make sure to run the following command for the first time to generate the related directories.

###### The latest version and workflow is for `Yarn 4.0.0-rc.48`

```bash
yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks base
```

You can read more about editor sdks in the [doc](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks#vscode)

Comment: There is no "sdks" folder inside ".yarn" folder. Are you sure that is the correct path?

Comment: @RuiMiguelPinheiro you must run `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks base`

Comment: that was the solution, I already had an `sdks` folder but not the `sdks/prettier` subfolder, after installing prettier you have to rerun `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks base`

Answer (score 5):

**With NPM**

```
npm install --save-dev prettier
```

**With Yarn**

```
yarn add --dev prettier
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my experience in the same case..

If you are running your project with some tool as `Docker`/`Warden`/etc and you are using all `npm`/`yarn` commands only inside the container shell then `Prettier` module will be invisible for your `IDE` like `Visual Studio Code`/`Atom`/etc..

To fix this problem please install the `Prettier` module and other modules (command `npm install`/`yarn install`) outside of the container on your local drive.. this kind of approach will fix the Prettier module problem and you will be able to use formatting with your IDE or system shell..

Comment: What is "container shell" in this context?

Comment: @RuiMiguelPinheiro - it is a bash shell you can access by using command similar to this one: docker exec -it YOUR-NODEJS-CONTAINER /bin/bash